# callbacks question

Tags: c

Basically im trying to make a dispatcher, but it fails because it's always "!event->callback_function", my code:

```
#include "event.h"
#include "memory.h"
#include "thread.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

bool running;

typedef struct Event {
    event_callback_t cb;
    time_t delay;
    void* p;
    struct Event* next;
} Event;

Event* g_events;

void _remove_event           __P((Event**, Event *));
void event_dispatch_internal        __P(());
void add_event_internal             __P((Event**, Event *));

void
event_dispatch()
{
    g_events = (Event *)MyMalloc(sizeof(*g_events));
    create_thread((callback_t)event_dispatch_internal, (void *)NULL);
}

void
add_event_internal(Event** events, Event* event)
{
    event->next = *events;
    *events = event;
}

void
add_event(callback, param, delay)
    event_callback_t callback;
    void *param;
    time_t delay;
{
    Event* event;
    event = (Event *)MyMalloc(sizeof(*event));
    assert(0 != event);

    event->delay = time(NULL) + delay;
    event->p = param;
    event->cb = callback;
    add_event_internal(&g_events, event);
}

void
_remove_event(Event** events, Event* event)
{
    event = *events;
    *events = event->next;
}

void
event_dispatch_internal()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Events started\n");
#endif
    while (true) {
        Event* tmp;
        for (tmp = g_events; tmp; tmp = tmp->next) {
            if (time(NULL) >= tmp->delay) {
                tmp->cb(tmp->p);
#ifdef _DEBUG
                fprintf(stderr, "Executed event %p:%u\n", (void *)tmp, (unsigned int)tmp->delay);
#endif
                _remove_event(&g_events, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it crashes but when i do it like that:

```
            for (tmp = g_events; tmp; tmp = tmp->next) {
            if (time(NULL) >= tmp->delay) {
                if (!tmp->cb) {
                    tmp->cb(tmp->p);
#ifdef _DEBUG
                    fprintf(stderr, "Executed event %p:%u\n", (void *)tmp, (unsigned int)tmp->delay);
#endif
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Couldnt execute event %p:%u\n", (void *)tmp, (unsigned int)tmp->delay);
                }
            }
        }
```

it always gives "Couldn't execute event blabla"

while i call it like that:

```
void test_(void *);

void
test_(void *p)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "test(): %d\n", *(int *)p);
}

int main()
{
    int test;
    test = 5;
    event_dispatch();
    add_event(test_, (void *)&test, 1);
    do { } while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

any help is apperciated

Comment: Woah - please format your code.

Comment: I always fail at making it lol, sorry

Comment: @Fallen: Select the code and press CTRL+K.

Comment: ok thanks, any answers related to the question? :P

Comment: We can't see the details of `event_callback_t`.  For new code, there is really no point in using the `_P((...))` mechanism; that was a transitional aid between pre-standard and standard C compilers.  The declaration of `event_dispatch_internal()` doesn't do what you think it does. It says that the function returns no value and can take any argument list whatsoever; you probably wanted `void event_dispatch_internal(void);` (or, in your notation, `void event_dispatch_internal __P((void));`).

Comment: The `add_event()` function should not be write in non-prototype notation.  We don't know what your thread package looks like.  You have no multi-thread access control (mutexes, etc) on what seems to be shared variables between threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't make *any* sense.  You fire off a thread, which then loops forever trying to walk the `g_events` list.  However, at startup, that just has a single, uninitialised node in it, so anything could happen!

Furthermore (1), you have no synchronization between your threads, so even if you fix the above problem, you're likely to get into nasty race hazards when people try to add events.

Furthermore (2), both your threads are effectively in "busy-wait" loops, which will suck your CPU dry.  You need to investigate a mechanism that causes your threads to sleep until something arrives, such as semaphores.